# Static Library works fine with debug,but does not with release

Tags: ios, iphone, static-libraries

I have an `iOS` project which has a static library and in the library there is a encrypt method and in the method it refers a lot of system encrypt method about `AES encryption.` When I build the static library with release,it returned the correct data.But when I build with debug mode,it returns nil.

- What's the differences between the two modes？
- The same source code can build out different binary files that works differently?

Help me,thanks beforehand. This is where I choose the two modes.

[image]

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784583/xcode-debug-vs-release-build-when-debugging

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is the level of compiler optimization. Select the project target and look at the Build Settings and compare Debug to Release.

One potential reason for the crash is that the code has some memory usage errors that by coincidence do not cause a crash with code optimization but do with no optimization. Or there are some other configuration difference. See the comment by @iDev.

A starting point is to fix all warnings, both compiler and Analyzer. The examine the crash log to understand the crash. If you need help with that add a crash report to your question.

Comment: Now I find out the differences between building the static library with debug and release.But when I get the .m or .mm out of the static library and put them into the Project,then build them.The result is that the encrypt method in the .m returns nil.why the same code,different results? Does it mean the optimizer when I build the static library help me? How to make the encrypt method works fine in the Project not just in the static library?